# Preambule? How to call the first part of a book?

Tags: word-choice

Is the small part of text before chapters usually called preambule? Or introduction perhaps?

Comment: Are you looking for *preamble*?

Comment: @deadrat I think so. Is this the relevant word?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please [edit] your post to include information about which text specifically you are referring to— and what research you have attempted, for example, on the parts of a book. You may be referring to *front matter*, including the *title page* and the *dedication* and the *epigraph*, or perhaps the *preface* or the *introduction* or the *foreword*, the *acknowledgments*, the *prologue*, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple words that may fit what you are trying to say. A [**preamble**](http://thefreedictionary.com/preamble) is a preliminary statement, so if you have perhaps a page or so to introduce a book, that is the right word to use. Otherwise you may simply want to use [**introduction**](http://thefreedictionary.com/introduction), being something used to introduce something else. If you are referring to the one- or two-paragraph description found on the inside covers and backs of books, you are thinking of a [**blurb**](http://thefreedictionary.com/blurb). Another possibility is [**foreword**](http://thefreedictionary.com/foreword), which is generally used only for introductions to books or other literature.